# Xcode 7 Cannot load underlying module for AlamoFire 3.x (CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I use Alamofire 3.3 with Xcode 7.1.1, installed with Cocoapods
and I have this problem a couple of time :

**Cannot load underlying module for Alamofire**

here it's my Podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end
```

I heard about the **same problem with Xcode 6.3** and it helped me to 
solve the problem once by cleaning project, but this time, I tryed to

- Clean Project
- Clean Xcode derived data and cache
- update with version 3.1 3.2 and 3.3 of Alamofire
- List item

... and nothing seams to work

does someone have the same troubles ? or any solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve it for you but usually this occurs when you are trying to include a framework that hasn't been built yet.

Have you tried Product -> Build yet?

Comment: Thanks it solves the problem for now by change the scheme to Alamofire and build. But it's strange cause  Alamofire was working well, and then, after adding a "Import Alamofire" in my code the error occured ... (I mean with no change to Alamofire version or anything about my pods :/ )

Comment: Seems too simple to work especially after cleaning, quitting, and building the project without the `import` statement prior to building it with (as I've seen recommended in other answers), but switching to the framework target and building it then switching back to the app target and rebuilding (as this answer says) solved the issue.

Comment: I've encountered this problem many time before.  I have found that immediately after importing the module, always build the project and it seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is small bug on cocoapods install
Please try again after clean and build
if still not working, turn off xcode and try again
it worked on my side

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,uninstall pod & install again . It worked for me , hope this will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 9:
Once you have installed Alamofire pod.

Step.1 you should open your project by double click on your_project_name.xcworkspace file.

Step.2 Go to project settings --> Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries --> Add framework "Alamofire.framework"

Thats it!!

Now you can import the module

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Kill Xcode and do `pod update`. Open Xcode, clean and build. This should fix it.